# Comparing Two Major Workbooks By Two Columns and many Params

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code to compare two rows in two different workbooks that can be located at different places among the column. The first column is usually grouped (multiple of the same value) in one section. This is why In this code I search by the first column, then pick the other identifier column and offset one at a time while both workbook sheets match each other

I am trying to activate the cell that I find via the .Find function in this code, but apparently you can't do that. "Active method of range class failed"

I believe that I am on the right track with this code, but I'm sure there are still issues, I'm trying to solve one problem at a time with my limited skills!

Thanks for the help :)

```
Sub Compare2()
    Dim layer As String
    Dim Pno As String
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Option Explicit
        For i = 5 To 1000 Step 1
            layer = Sheets("MP Parameters").Range("A" & i).Value
            Pno = Sheets("MP Parameters").Range("H" & i).Value
            With Sheets("Compare").Range("a1:a1500")
                Set c = .Find(layer, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = c.Address
                    c.Activate
                    Do
                        Sheets("Compare").ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=7).Activate
                        If Sheets("Compare").ActiveCell = Pno Then
                            Sheets("Compare").ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=9).Activate
                            If Sheets("Compare").ActiveCell.Value <> Sheets("MP Parameters").Range("P" & i).Value Then
                                Sheets("MP Parameters").Range("P" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                            End If
                        End If
                        Set c = .FindNext(c)
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                i = i + 1
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: as first step: change `c.Address.ActivateCell` to `c.Activate`

Comment: Thanks! It's the little things that I always miss

Comment: Still it throws the error "Active method of range class failed"

Comment: Changed to add "Dim c As Range" and added Option Explicit

Comment: Is Sheets("Compare") the active sheet?  You can't Activate a cell that isn't on the active sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `Activate` a cell if it's on the `ActiveSheet`. Since your code references then `Activates` cells on different sheets, you will cause errors.

You have two options.

Either activate the appropriate sheet first:

```
Sheet1.Activate
Range("A2").Activate
```

Or, don't activate a sheet to do a conditional check. You don't have to activate a cell to determine what it's value is. As an example, if you wanted to check what value is in sheet1, cell B2 (irrespective of which sheet is active in the workbook):

```
If Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = "Yes" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code within your `If Not c Is Nothing` ... `End If` block can be changed to:

```
firstAddress = c.Address
Do
    If c.Offset(0, 7).Value = Pno Then
        If c.Offset(0, 16).Value <> Sheets("MP Parameters").Range("P" & i).Value Then
            Sheets("MP Parameters").Range("P" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        End If
    End If
    Set c = .FindNext(c)
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
i = i + 1
```

(I'm not sure what the `i = i + 1` is meant to be doing.  I've always found it dangerous to modify the loop counter manually.  But I left it there as hopefully it is doing what you want it to do.)